# Управление элементами Custom Dialog Android

Tags: java, android, android-dialog, android-layout-inflater

Есть задача сделать `SeekBar` для `MediaPlayer`. `SeekBar` находится в `Dialog`, который основан на `layout.xml`, т.е. `custom`. Пробовал через `LayoutInflater`, но такое впечатление что элементы теперь видит, но сделать с ними ничего нельзя.

Привожу код. В `protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` у меня есть `ListView` и установлен на него `list1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()`. На клик создаю `dialog`:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(music_act.this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.playdialog);
dialog.setTitle("Сейчас играет");
TextView dtitle = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView);
dtitle.setText(((TextView) itemClicked).getText());
dialog.show();
```

В диалоге по нажатию на кнопку делаю

```
public void onClickP(View v) {
            LayoutInflater factory = getLayoutInflater();
            View dial = factory.inflate(R.layout.playdialog, null);
            buttonP = (Button)dial.findViewById(R.id.button);
                if (mediaPl.isPlaying() == true) {
                    mediaPl.pause();
                    buttonP.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_black_48dp);
                } else if (mediaPl.isPlaying() == false) {
                    mediaPl.start();
                    buttonP.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_black_48dp);
                }
        }
```

Но! Фон кнопки не изменяется, и вообще ничего не происходит кроме запуска и паузы плеера (управление другими элементами удалил; осуществлялось таким же образом). Никаких крашей и записей в логах.

Вопрос: как правильно управлять элементами в `Dialog`, если он создан на основе `layout.xml`. По возможности: как прикрутить в таком случаем `SeekBar` к `MediaPlayer`. Спасибо за Ваше время.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С помощью `LayoutInflater` загружают разметку из `xml` для последующего добавления её в иерархию отображаемого на экране. Он не предназначен для поиска уже отображаемых элементов разметки. Т.е. в вашем коде вы меняете фон неотображаемому на экране компоненту.

Вам надо не загружать новую разметку, а искать элементы в уже отображаемой. В вашем случае вам надо получать разметку вашего диалога из него же. Вроде бы для этого используется метод `getCustomView()`

Если обработчик приведённый вами повешен на кнопку в диалоге, то вы можете использовать аргумент обработчика для нахождения элементов разметки диалога.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{

    Dialog dialog;

    public void onCreate(Bundle b){
        dialog = new Dialog(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View v){
        TextView dtitle = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        dtitle.setText("CLICKED!!!11");
    }

}
```

Comment: Вопрос в догонку: как мне вынести правильно в переменные строку `final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(music_act.this);` чтобы можно было достучаться к нему с помощью `Button buttonP; buttonP = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.button);` из `onClick`?
А так - огромное Вам спасибо!

Comment: @ArthurAlekseenko, недостаточно информации для ответа. Диалог как переменную можно сделать полем класса активити. Тогда его даже `final` можно не делать. Про кнопку не скажу - мне не ясно где она

Comment: кнопка находится в `xml`, из которого сделан `dialog`, а `onClick` - отдельный `public void` в этом же классе

Comment: @ArthurAlekseenko, если диалог у вас поле класса активити и onClick метод класса активити, то в onClick у вас есть доступ к dialog и его разметке.

Comment: но доступа нет. Что изменить? Диалог объявлял внутри `onCreate`. Когда выношу в поля - ругается на `final Dialog dialog = new Dialog ** (music_act.this); ** ` и крашится

Comment: На уровне класса контекста у вас нет и что за "полужирный"?.. Вам надо объявить диалог на уровне класса, а инициализировать уже вв onCreate;

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать) уже отмечаю Ваш ответ верным)) P.S.: насчет полужирного - не выходит выделить почему-то нужный фрагмент

Comment: @ArthurAlekseenko, я всё ещё не очень понимаю в чём у вас проблема, но примерный код набросал в ответе.

Comment: Помогло. Огромное Вам спасибо!