# Получить view из другого xml

Tags: java, android, android-layout-inflater

Как получить `View` с другого xml, пишу следующий код в `MainActivity`, но он не работает:

```
    View inflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, null);
    TextView text = (TextView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    text.setText("Hello!");
```

Comment: Что именно *не работает*? Код правильный, должен работать.

Comment: Опишите точнее, что не работает? Вываливается ошибка? Или просто никакой реакции? и где на вашей активити вы используете этот fragment_navigation_drawer.xml?

Comment: В вашем куске кода ошибок нет, дайте больше инфы)

Comment: никакой реакции , fragment_navigation_drawer.xml это первый  item в listview , там два текста и картинка

Comment: Аналогичная проблема [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/506066/17609)

Comment: а реакции и не будет, вы не добавляете View На экран.

Comment: Android Studio лишь инструмент, одна из IDE для разработки под Android, в вашем вопросе упоминание о этой программе совершенно лишнее, аналогичное решение будет применимо и для любой другой среды разработки под Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы уже третий человек за три дня кто неправильно использует `LayoutInflater`.

Он используется лишь для загрузки новой разметки из xml и отображения её на экране. До тех пор, пока вы не добавитье загруженное на экран вы его не увидите.

Вам надо не `LayoutInflater` а искать нужные вам и уже отобрааемые на экране элементы разметки методами `finViewById` активити.

---

```
NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(...);
View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
TextView text = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
```

Comment: обьесню , на версии 19 я добавлял сам  верхнюю картинку в navbar , в   android studio дается  navbar material гтэ там уже есть , первый пункт с картинками и текстам я пробовал много раз получить первый пункт  но не получилось и я обратился за помощью . спасибо за ваши помошь

Comment: @DavidKern, вам надо HeaderView у NavigationView получить?..

Comment: да , наверное я неправильно выразился при задании вопроса

Comment: @DavidKern, см. обновлённый ответ